# Vue-router reloads page and I lose my state, how do i avoid this?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router, vuex, vue-material

I have a form divided in 5 components and the user can navigate through them via steppers (I'm using vue-material for my project). I use vue-router for that. However, I'm having a serious issue here: components lose all the information in the store (I'm using vuex) when they come back to a route they already filled. So to make it clear: if a user fills the first step of the form and then goes to step two, when he wants to come back to step one data is no longer available and the form is totally empty (and the state in vuex is also reset). What am i doing wrong?

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Projet from '@/components/Fiches/Projet/Projet'


Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Projet
},
//other routes here
]
})
```

And this is the html code

```
<template>
 <div class="project-steppers">
   <md-steppers md-dynamic-height md-alternative>
      <md-step id="first" to="/Projet" md-label="Projet" />
       // other steps here
    </md-steppers>
  </div>
</template>
```

And an example of one of the inputs I use:

```
      <md-field>
        <label for="project-name">Nom du projet</label>
        <md-input id="project-name"
                  v-model="project.projectName"
                  name="project-name"
                  @change="updateProjectName"/>
      </md-field>

[...]
  methods: {
updateProjectName () {
  this.$store.commit(projectStore.MUTATE_PROJECTNAME, this.project.projectName)
}
```

**More information:** when I fill the different inputs I see that the store is updated with the new values, so the mutation is working.

Comment: you could use tabs[(see the MD docs for tabs)](https://material.io/design/components/tabs.html) for each step, instead of route changes. The state is lost when you refresh the page or change the route.

Comment: Where do you read the information from the store? You should do that when your component is created, so the fields are filled

Answer (score 4):

First of all, Vuex does not store data in the browser - just in memory. That means that you could either install a third party plugin such as [vuex persisted state](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) or write your own methods to `set` and `get` the items from your storage, e.g.:

```
const storage = localStorage.getItem('key');

new Vuex({
   state: {
     yourProp: storage ?
        ? JSON.parse(storage.yourDataKey)
        : 'default-value'
   },
   actions: {...}
   mutations: {...}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think to should use `router-link` or `$router.push()`.

Vue:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import Projet1 from '@/components/Fiches/Projet/Projet1'
import Projet2 from '@/components/Fiches/Projet/Projet2'
import Projets from '@/components/Fiches/Projet/Projet' //with props

Vue.use(Router)     

export default new Router({
routes: [
{
  path: '/',
  name: 'Home',
  component: Projet1 // default project
},
    {
  path: '/Projet1',  // url for the same component
  name: 'Projet1',
  component: Projet1
},
{
  path: '/Project2',
  name: 'Projet2', // url for the another component
  component: Projet2
},
{
  path: '/Project/:id',
  name: 'Projets', // url for a component with props 
  component: Projet,
  props: true
}
]
})
```

HTML: A way to call Projet without reloading with `router-link`

```
<template>
<router-link to="/Home"></router>
<router-link to="/Projet1"></router>
<router-link to="/Projet2"></router>
</template>
```

js: I would add a router push

```
updateProjectName () {
  this.$store.commit(projectStore.MUTATE_PROJECTNAME, this.project.projectName)
  this.$router.push('/' + this.project.projectName)
}
```

Your question looks like the issue opened by kristianmandrup:
[menu or tabs with router links!?](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/785)